# How do I populate a cell in one spreadsheet to a cell in another spreadsheet in the same workbook?

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Spreadsheets I have created a master spreadsheet that I complete with the amounts of the items needed. I would like those numbers to auto populate in each individual spreadsheet in the workbook.

How do I do this?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear to me. You have one Spreadsheet and you want to import specific data into another spreadsheet, more specifically sheets?

Answer (score 1):

You can't "push" a value (say from master spreadsheet to another) but you can "pull". So if A1 in Sheet1 is say `333` you can call that up in another sheet with `=Sheet1!A1`, or if say `01/01/1900` in Sheet1 you might give that a name, say `bDay` and use `=bDay` in another sheet to call up `01/01/1900`.

Unfortunately I am not aware of a 'Group' facility for New Google Sheets (such as Excel has) and whatever you do seems will be required for each `individual spreadsheet` separately.